# Adding data from one list to another using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to populate a dropdown in my UI and hence added List object to the view model in my c# application. I am fetching the data in my controller code for the dropdown. What's the best way to assign data to the viewmodel object. Is linq an option?

I basically need to assign fundclasses to fundTrackRecord.FundClass

The main Viewmodel:

```
public class FundPerformanceVM
{
    public FundPerformanceVM()
    {
        TrackRecord = new List<TrackRecordVM>();
    }

    public int FundId { get; set; }
    public string FundName { get; set; }
    public List<FundClassVM> FundClass { get; set; }
    public string BenchmarkName1 { get; set; }
    public string BenchmarkName2 { get; set; }
    public List<TrackRecordVM> TrackRecord { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<string, string, string>> FundStatistics { get; set; }

}

public class FundClassVM
{
    public int FundClassId { get; set; }
    public string FundClass { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
var service = GetViewService<V_LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_SUMMARY>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<FUND_PERFORMANCE>> entry in allPerformance)
{
   var fundClasses = service.GetAll().Where(x => x.FUND_ID == entry.Key).Select(x => new { x.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID, x.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS}).ToList();
   var fundTrackRecord = new FundPerformanceVM();     

   fundTrackRecord.FundClass = ??;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the structure of your model, you can try this:

```
fundTrackRecord.FundClass = fundClasses.Select(fc => new FundClassVM
{
    FundClassId = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID,
    FundClass = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS
}).ToList();
```

You can also do this directly, replacing the code:

```
var fundClasses = service.GetAll().Where(x => x.FUND_ID == entry.Key).Select(x => new { x.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID, x.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS}).ToList();
var fundTrackRecord = new FundPerformanceVM();
```

With:

```
var fundTrackRecord = new FundPerformanceVM();
fundTrackRecord.FundClass = service.GetAll().
    Where(x => x.FUND_ID == entry.Key).
    Select(fc => new FundClassVM
    {
        FundClassId = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID,
        FundClass = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS
    }).ToList();
```